# Given two points A and B, how do you find Y according to X?

Tags: analytic-geometry

I have two points $ A = (3,5)$ and $B = (5,2)$, I want to find their midpoint C = (4, Y).

In this case Y would be 3.5

Is there a formula to find out what the $ Y $ of a point is, in relation to the other two points?

exemple:
Given A (3.5) B (5.2) complete:
C (4, Y), the answer would be: C (4.3.5);
C (3.5, Y), the answer would be: C (3.5,4.25);
C (4.5, Y), the answer would be: C (4.5,2.5);

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your example. What is $C$ and how did you conclude that $Y=3,5$. And by $Y=3,5$, do you mean that $Y$ is three and a half, or the coordinate $(3,5)$?

Comment: Y =  ( 4 , 3.5 )

Comment: I assume that you mean $C=(4,3.5)$

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry.

Comment: OK, so how did you conclude that? [Edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3584299/edit) your question to add your reasoning, instead of posting it as a comment as comments can be deleted without warning

Comment: I'm sorry, this is my first question here, I'm still not sure how it works, but I've already fixed the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are trying to do is find the midpoint of the line joining $A$ and $B$. If we generalise and say that \begin{align}A&=(x_A,y_A)\\
B&=(x_B,y_B)\end{align}

then the coordinates of the midpoint of the line joining them together can be written as

$$C=\left(\frac{x_A+x_B}{2},\frac{y_A+y_B}{2}\right)$$

In the example you gave, we have \begin{align}A&=(3,5)\\
B&=(5,2)\end{align}

Therefore \begin{align}C&=\left(\frac{3+5}{2},\frac{5+2}{2}\right)\\
&=\left(\frac82,\frac 72\right)\\
&=(4,3.5)\end{align}

---

If in fact what you are trying to do is simply find the point on the line joining $A$ and $B$, given an $x$-coordinate, then we need to find the equation of the line.

We need to know the slope of the line which is given by $$m=\frac{y_B-y_A}{x_B-x_A}$$

Now we can use the "[point slope formula](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/line-equation-2points.html)" to find the equation of the line:

$$y-y_A=m(x-x_A)$$

Therefore, the $y$ coordinate can be found using

\begin{align}y&=m(x-x_a)+y_A\\
&=\frac{y_B-y_A}{x_B-x_A} (x-x_A)+y_A\\
&=\frac{(y_B-y_A)(x-x_A)}{x_B-x_A}+y_A\end{align}

For our example, this is the same as saying

\begin{align}Y&=\frac{(2-5)(x-3)}{5-3}+5\\
&=\frac{-3(x-3)}{2}+5\end{align}

When we have $C=(4,Y)$, then this gives

\begin{align}Y&=\frac{-3(4-3)}{2}+5\\
&=\frac{-3\times 1}{2}+5\\
&=5-\frac 32\\
&=3.5\end{align}

or, for $C=(3.5,Y)$, we would have

\begin{align}Y&=\frac{-3(3.5-3)}{2}+5\\
&=\frac{-3\times0.5}{2}+5\\
&=\frac{-1.5}2+5\\
&=5-0.75\\
&=4.25\end{align}

This is slightly different to the result you are expecting, but I believe your result is wrong and this is what you intended

Comment: But what if X is 3.5? the Y would be 4.5, but which formula do I use?

Comment: Why would $X$ be $3.5$? Either you are trying to find the mid point or you are not, in which case you need to add some more details about what you actually want to know

Comment: I have two vertices, A and B, which form a line, I have an X number that can be any number between Ax and Bx, so I want to find the Y, ex:
Given A (3.5) B (5.2) complete:
C (4, Y), the answer would be: C (4.3.5)
C (3.5, Y), the answer would be: C (3.5,4.5)
C (4.5, Y), the answer would be: C (4.5,2.5)

Comment: With your A and B, having X=3.5 would give you Y=4.25 if you’re trying to find the corresponding point on the line joining A and B

Comment: I've updated my answer with another option which may answer your quesiton

Comment: Yes, thanks you, to this is what I needed, but I didn't know where to find the answer, you helped me a lot! ^ - ^